# Runtime migration from python2.7 to 3.8

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working to move the AWS lambda function from the current runtime of python 2.7 to 3.8. I have run 2to3 on the function but I am not getting any changes that may be needed.  am I able to just move to change the run time to 3.8 without any issues?

```
import json
import boto3
import urllib3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

def handler(event, context):
    try:
        bucketNames = event['ResourceProperties']['BucketNames']

        if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
            for bucketName in bucketNames:
                s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

                try:
                    s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket=bucketName)

                    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketName)
                    for obj in bucket.objects.filter():
                        s3.Object(bucket.name, obj.key).delete()
                except ClientError:
                    # Bucket already removed/never existed
                    pass

        sendResponseCfn(event, context, "SUCCESS")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sendResponseCfn(event, context, "FAILED")


def sendResponseCfn(event, context, responseStatus):
    response_body = {'Status': responseStatus,
                     'Reason': 'Log stream name: ' + context.log_stream_name,
                     'PhysicalResourceId': context.log_stream_name,
                     'StackId': event['StackId'],
                     'RequestId': event['RequestId'],
                     'LogicalResourceId': event['LogicalResourceId'],
                     'Data': json.loads("{}")}

    http.request('PUT', event['ResponseURL'], body=json.dumps(response_body))
```

Current output using 2to3

```
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
RefactoringTool: No changes to index.py
RefactoringTool: Files that need to be modified:
RefactoringTool: index.py
```

Comment: "am I able to just move to change the run time to 3.8 without any issues" – seems so. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Test it. Also, why are you calling `bucket.objects.filter()` with no filter? Also, your catchall `except ClientError` is not ideal - it will swallow all kinds of potential errors.